# Find a field by input type

Tags: css, capybara

Is there a way that I can find all fields that are input, type=email?

Here's an HTML snippet:

```
<input id="keeper-email_email" name="keeper-email.email" value="" 
       aria-describedby="keeper-email_email-hint" no_optional_label="true" 
       type="email" autocomplete="off" maxlength="254">
```

I can see that has an ID and so on but that changes depending on certain criteria.  I was hoping to write a method that could identify any field that is type email and enter the required email address.

Is there a way to do this with Capybara?

I've tried:

```
all('input[type='email']")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep it readable, you want the `type` option of the `:field` selector

```
fields = all(:field, type: 'email')
fields[0].set('bla')
fields[1].set('blo')
```

and if you know there is going to be one at least one field you probably want

```
all(:field, type: 'email', minimum: 1)
```

so that it utilizes Capybaras waiting behavior for at least one field to appear (if you know there will be exactly 2 use `count: 2` as an option instead)

Another option if there is only going to be one would be

```
find_field(type: 'email')
```

If rather than matching on the type of the fields you want to check the label for the partial text 'email' you could also do

```
all(:field, 'email', exact: false) # The same count/minimum/etc options from above can be used here too
```

Answer (score 1):

After a little playing around, I came up with the following that works:

```
emails = all(:xpath, "//label[contains(text(), 'email')]")
email = emails[0].text
email_2 = emails[1].text
fill_in(email, with: 'bla')
fill_in(email_2, with: 'blo')
```

This works because every email form has the word 'email' in its label text.

Comment: See my answer - it's more readable, will be more reliable (when using the count/minimum/etc options), and will be more performant (calling set vs fill_in which does another find)